# Use of be with is/am/are/was/were

Tags: verbs, infinitives, subjunctives

It is necessary that all documents, in original, ______ Submitted.

(a) Are
(b) Be
(c) To Be
(d) Are To be

My Text book prefers (b) Be

Comment: Well , My Text book prefers (b) Be.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: To make this a  better question, please tell us why you doubt the textbook.  Why do you not think that "be" is clearly the correct answer?

Comment: First, your [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/319012/use-of-be-with-is-am-are-was-were#comment599474_319012) should be included in your post, please [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/319012/edit) to add it. Second, what's your question??? Are you asking why the answer is (b)??? If so, remember to also include it in your question, and tell us which one do you think is correct and why.

Comment: I've downvoted your post, please see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options a or b both fit in the space. But the word order would be improved as :

***It is necessary that all documents are/be submitted in original (form).***

You could also use option d, but in that case you would not need - and could not include *it is necessary that*. One would say:

***All documents are to be submitted in original (form).***

Option c on its own is not usable unless it is just a foot or marginal note, or final clause. Because there would not be a finite verb:

***All documents to be submitted in original (form)***.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "are".  The subject (documents) is plural, and verbal agreement would normally require the third person plural form of the verb, which is "are".

*However*, this test question is actually trying to test if you were paying attention when you were taught about the English subjunctive.  The construction "be necessary that something (...) done" is one of the constructions in English that *permits* but *does not require* the subjunctive.  The subjunctive form of the verb is "be".

It is a poor question. The answer "are" is also correct, but you will lose marks if you choose it because you have to guess that the question is actually about testing if you know the subjunctive.  It is also rather unnaturally phrased. The expression "in original" is odd.  Unfortunately there are tests like this, which test some aspect of grammar that is obsolete and unnecessary, and aren't even examples of well-written English.